# pymysql & RDS IAM user

Tags: amazon-rds, pymysql

Has anyone been able to connect to an RDS host using an IAM user with Pymysql?

https://gist.github.com/kave/4fcdef69ae3007148190516e1e11b48d
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.Connecting.Python.html

Both of these examples are wrong or outdated.

"generate_db_auth_token" retruns a full URL. In no way does this work as a password.

Comment: I swapped out Pymysql for mysql.connect and i'm having the exact same issue.

Comment: Finally got this to work. It's because the password gets encrypted by default and it doesn't like this when using AWS tokens. You also must SSL. `conn = pymysql.connect(auth_plugin_map = {'mysql_clear_password':None}, ssl={'ca': 'global-bundle.pem'}, host=db['host'], port=db.get('port',3306), user=db['user'], password=passwd, connect_timeout=db.get('connect_timeout',10), read_timeout=db.get('read_timeout',10), write_timeout=db.get('write_timeout',10))`

Comment: won't work with mysql.connect driver--doesn't like the length of the token. `"errorMessage": "ubyte format requires 0 <= number <= 255",`